# Radio buttons in MFC (re-written)

Tags: c++, mfc, radio-button

So I'm working on a class project that uses MFC. I never had to learn how to work with MFC since I was making the character class stuff (D&D game).

I currently have the radio buttons working. So I know which was pressed and can retrieve it.

My problem is this: I have 2 radio buttons, which represent the 2 sets of 6 dice rolls to be used for stats.

I want to display a string containing the set for the specific radio button. So what I'm wondering is: is there a way to have the caption string for a radio button be equal to a specific string that can change between the times the dialog with said radio button is opened?

Edit: I changed the whole question since I solved all but this part of the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC wraps radio buttons in [CButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1wax6c.aspx) instances, so you can use their [SetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhczy8bz.aspx) method:

```
yourRadioButton.SetWindowText(_T("New Text"));
```

Comment: How do I use it on a specific radio button?

Comment: That depends on the way you're storing the buttons. You can either use member variables of the dialog box in conjunction with `DDX_Control()`, or perform explicit calls to `GetDlgItem()`. I might be able to help further if you update your question with the relevant parts of your current code.

Comment: Is this call correct? GetDlgItem(IDC_SET_1)->SetWindowTextA(_T("%s",cSet1)); cSet1 is a CString.

Comment: I put a break point right on that line and as soon as i step into it is get this: Unhandled exception at 0x762e7a19 in comp345_dnd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefefe.

Comment: You cannot pass formatting arguments to `_T()`, so you might want to create a `CString` object instead. On the other hand, that's not really necessary since you don't have anything to format (you already have a string in `cSet1`). Also, you should call `SetWindowText()` instead of `SetWindowTextA()`. Something like `GetDlgItem(IDC_SET_1)->SetWindowText(cSet1);`.

Comment: setWindowTextA is the only one that appears in intellisense. I tried your last line with and without A and it failed. cSet1 is a CString right?

Comment: You shouldn't blindly follow Intellisense's completions (it lists `SetWindowTextA()` because your project is in ANSI mode now, but the actual method is indeed `SetWindowText()`. Intellisense would list `SetWindowTextW()` if your project was in UNICODE mode). Does the code still fail with `0xc0000005`? Can you verify that `GetDlgItem()` returns a valid `CWnd *`? Are you running this code during the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler of your dialog box?

Comment: What's WM_INITDIALOG? it's not in the .cpp file.

Comment: Same fail code. The SetWindowTextA function says it's a function of CWnd.

Comment: Can you see an `OnInitDialog()` method? That's the MFC handler for the `WM_INITDIALOG` message. The code to change the radio button text should be put there if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: The string doesn't exist in the entire solution

Comment: You will probably have to add this method then. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Is the entry in the header: afx_msg bool OnInitDialog() ?

Comment: Very weird, the CStrings contain random stuff, the first is random and the second is empty it seems.

Comment: You have a misplaced parenthesis that ends up passing all the formatting arguments to the `_T()` macro. You have to write `cSet1.Format(_T("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d"), set1[0], set1[1], set1[2], set1[3], set1[4], set1[5]);` to obtain the results you're expecting.

Comment: Really? This explains another error somewhere else... Fixed those lines though, but it still shows: 18, 15 in one and blank in the other.

Comment: Strange, there are six format arguments so there's no way you would end up with only two values in the resulting string. Maybe you're modifying them later?

Comment: The positions in the vector? They're only accessed after the dialog closes, they're never passed into it so those events shouldn't happen until the dialog closes.

Comment: This is literally how the dialog is made then used: CharGen* dialog = new CharGen(cSet1,cSet2,NULL); dialog->DoModal();

Comment: Maybe you're reusing `cSet1` and `cSet2` for another purpose between the calls to `Format()` and the time you pass them to your dialog's constructor?

Comment: The only potential problem I see with that code is that the base class call to `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` on line 68 should be `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()`, but that doesn't explain your issue... Can you set a breakpoint on line 17 and verify that `cSet1` and `cSet2` are valid at that point?

Comment: OMG! I called set1 twice in there! So set2 is never defined. /facepalm

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. The six values are there, but you only see two *because the radio button controls are not wide enough*. Can you increase their width in the dialog template?

Comment: Ok, weird, cSet1 & cSet2 both are correct in the call GetDlgItem(IDC_SET_1)->SetWindowTextA(cSet1); when I hover over cSet1/2

Comment: It works now, I'm about to fall asleep at the keyboard. Time to push it so my team can have it while i sleep in late.

Comment: You have way more patience than I deserve.